# Execute multiple stored procedures based on the parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute multiple stored procedures based on parameter. I have one stored procedure where it calls 5 stored procedures. Each stored procedure returns different result sets.

As a parameter I'm passing `'Notes,Viewers,Editors,..etc'`. Based on this list I need to execute and get all the results and return it.

Currently what I'm trying is follows;

- Insert the parameter into a temp table as table rows.
- Using a cursor iterate through the table rows and execute the stored procedures.
- Inside the cursor I'm checking

  ```
   if @row = 'Editor' EXEC sp 1
   else if @row = 'Viewers' EXEC sp 2
   ...
   ...
  ```

At the end of this iteration I need to return all the results.

So my question is, Is this the best way to get it done OR are there any good solutions to cater these kind of operations.

Comment: Can you not conditionally `exec` into a single temporary table (or table-valued variable) and then return that?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```
if (@param like '%Editors%') exec sp1
if (@param like '%Viewers%') exec sp2
```

Or is the order of the values important?

Comment: Yes. order matters. Need to make sure the result i get is relevant to the name. eg 'Editor' I need to populate dataset based on the relevant name.